# How to make the NVDA narrator to read datagrid row background color?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Working on a vb.net appln. I have a data grid with rows that has Red, yellow and green background based on the status of the record. For accessibility purpose I'm using NVDA narrator to read the UI. How to make the narrator read the gridview row backcolor?

Not sure if I had to use AccessibilityObject?

Comment: Why not just add a column that has the value of the color?

Comment: Is it possible to read on row saying "this is primary row"